# Probability of getting 3 3s throwing 3 dice 3 times and saving the 3s

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

You can throw 3 dice 3 times. Every time a 3 comes, you save it and don't throw it any more. What are the odds you will end up with 3 3 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some hint:
Conditioning on the result of the first throw:
Let $A_0$ = {the first throw doesn't have 3}, $A_1$ = {the first throw has one 3},
$A_2$ = {the first throw has two 3s},
$A_3$ = {the first throw has three 3s} and $A$ = {ends up with 3, 3, 3}. 
By law of total probability:
$$P(A) = P(A|A_0)P(A_0) + P(A|A_1)P(A_1) + P(A|A_2)P(A_2) + P(A|A_3)P(A_3)$$
Finding $P(A|A_0)$, $P(A|A_1)$ and $P(A|A_2)$ are just "fractal" problems of the original problem. It is also easy to find $P(A_i), i = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

Comment: This makes sense! I'll try to solve it. But I also should consider $A_0$, right?

Comment: Why? The first throw might be {2,4,6}, then the second throw might be {3,3,3}.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some R code to check against the theoretical derivation:

```
perce=0; T=10^7
for (t in 1:T){
  # first throw
  res=sample(1:6,3,rep=TRUE) 
  val=sum(res==3)
  # second throw
  if (val<3){ res=sample(1:6,3-val,rep=TRUE)
    val=val+sum(res==3)}
  # third throw
  if (val<3){ res=sample(1:6,3-val,rep=TRUE)
    val=val+sum(res==3)}
  perce=perce+(val==3)}
perce/T
```